# can you do an if statement after an if statement?

Tags: java, html, if-statement

My BMR calculator isnt giving me the correct result, I know if I take out the if loop that checks the activity is the right answer but I can't find what needs to be changed

```
double doubleweight = Double.parseDouble(Weight);
double doubleage = Double.parseDouble(Age);
double doubleheight = Double.parseDouble(Height);

double BMRm, BMRf;
BMRm = 66 + (6.23 * doubleweight) + (12.7 * doubleheight) - (6.8 * doubleage);
BMRf = 655 + (4.35 * doubleweight) + (4.7 * doubleheight) - (4.7 * doubleage);

double bmr;
if ((null != Gender) && "Female".equals(Gender)){
bmr=BMRf;
}
else{
    bmr=BMRm;
}

if ("sed".equals(Activity)){
    bmr=(bmr*1.2);
}
else if("lightact".equals(Activity)){
    bmr=(bmr*1.375);
}
else if("modact".equals(Activity)){
    bmr=(bmr*1.55);
}
else if("vact".equals(Activity)){
    bmr=(bmr*1.725);
}
else{
    bmr=(bmr*1.9);
}
```

Comment: "*[...] take out the if loop [...]*" - There is no such thing as an `if`-loop. Please provide an [MCVE].

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your problem. Could you provide examples (input values and expected versus actual output?)

Comment: @Turing well while I wouldn't use it, you find the term "if loop" even in literature eg. Wirth - can't say who came up with that or why. (but even so I don't understand the question, but it could be me)

Comment: @kai [Probably IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSHRK_4.2.0/ref/reference/ref_stifloop.html)

Comment: @janedoe please provide the input values with current outputs and expected outputs

Comment: It would also help to follow the Java coding conventions. The presence of a popular type name like `Activity` as what must be a variable name is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You would better use the **case** statement wich is more **simple**, very usefull specially when trying to code a calculator :

```
switch  (Activity) {
    case "sed" : bmr=(bmr*1.2);
    case "lightact" : bmr=(bmr*1.375);
    case "modact" : bmr=(bmr*1.55);
    case "vact" : bmr=(bmr*1.725);
    default: bmr=(bmr*1.9);
}
```

For best practices, the names of the attributes better be starting with  lowercase letters :

```
double bmrm = 66 + (6.23 * doubleweight) + (12.7 * doubleheight) - (6.8 * doubleage);
double bmrf = 655 + (4.35 * doubleweight) + (4.7 * doubleheight) - (4.7 * doubleage);
```

Comment: "otherwise Java will consider them classes" - that is nonsense, for Java the case of names doesn't matter. The recommendation is that attribute names should start with lower case letters, but that is just a recommendation, not a requirement (as opposed to for example Ruby)

Comment: Yes I'am sorry, you are right, I rectified my answer, it's a matter of naming cvonventions in Java

Comment: But do not lightly dismiss the importance of the naming conventions. "The compiler doesn't enforce them" doesn't make them less mandatory in practice.